# Document constructor with multiple signatures

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'd like to know how can I define two signatures for the constructor with jsdoc:

```
makeClass("Person",
/** @lends Person */
{
    /**
        @constructs
        @param {int} p1
    */
    /**
        @constructs
        @param {string} p1
    */
    constructor: function () {

    },

    /**
        @name Person.prototype.func
        @function
        @param {object} arg arg desc
    */
    /**
        @name Person.prototype.func^2
        @function
        @param {int} arg arg desc
        @param {int} arg2 arg2 desc
    */
    func: function () {

    }
});
```

This produces one constructor with {string} p1.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSDoc doesn't have a concept comparable to the Visual Studio XML Doc multiple signatures. One option would be to document parameters as having multiple possible types, and marking some optional.

```
/**
 * @param {Number|Object} arg Description of arg
 * @param {Number} [arg2] Description of arg2
 */
```

Comment: This is kind of useless though, because every single tool that taps into d.ts files will now go "this function takes two arguments, you provided only one, This is an error and I will keep highlighting it as such".

Answer (score 5):

[DocumentJS](https://github.com/bitovi/documentjs), the documentation tool used/created by the [JavascriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com) project has [released a new "@signature" annotation](https://gist.github.com/justinbmeyer/6171192#documentjs) that allows you to annotate multiple signatures for the same method.

I can't find much [documentation](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs/DocumentJS.tags.signature.html) but according to the [source](https://github.com/bitovi/canjs/blob/v1.1.7/observe/observe.js#L412) (edited for brevity) it looks straight forward:

```
   /**
     * @signature `observe.attr()`
     * @return {Object<String, *>} an object with all the properties in this `can.Observe`.
     * 
     * @signature `observe.attr(key)`
     * @param {String} key the property to read
     * @return {*} the value assigned to _key_.
     *
     * @signature `observe.attr(key, value)`
     * @param {String} key the property to set
     * @param {*} the value to assign to _key_.
     * @return {can.Observe} this Observe, for chaining
     */
   attr: function( attr, val ) {
```